# I'm having an error when trying to delete an object from the MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

When I give a GET I would like a certain object to be deleted from my database, but the program breaks when I do it, it follows a code sample:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetProdutos([FromQuery] string city)
    {

        var search = from p in _context.Produtos
                     where p.Nome == city
                     select p;

        if (search != null)
        {
            foreach (var p in search)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-20) < p.Id)
                {
                    return $"Clima em {p.Nome}:\nTemperatura atual: {p.Temp}\nTemperatura Máxima: {p.TempMax}\nTemperatura Mínima: {p.TempMin}";
                }
                else
                {
                    

                    _context.Produtos.Remove(p);
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                }
               
            }

        }
```

The program breaks when I try to execute the line:

```
_context.Produtos.Remove(p);
```

This is a summary of the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: This MySqlConnection is already in use.
```

I would like to know how to solve this problem...

I'm studying programming so any clarification will be very welcome...

Comment: Call `_context.SaveChangesAsync()` outside of the loop? I'm guessing because I don't use EntityFramework, which is what I assume you're using.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 if (search != null)
 {
  var productList= new List<Produto>();
   foreach (var p in search)
  {
    if (DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-20) < p.Id)
    {
      return $"Clima em {p.Nome}:\nTemperatura atual: {p.Temp}\nTemperatura Máxima: {p.TempMax}\nTemperatura Mínima: {p.TempMin}";
     }
     else productList.Add(p);
 }
   if(productList.Count >0)
   {
    _context.Produtos.RemoveRange(productList);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
}
```

And IMHO

```
if (DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-20) < p.Id)
    {
      return $"Clima em {p.Nome}:\nTemperatura atual: {p.Temp}\nTemperatura Máxima: {p.TempMax}\nTemperatura Mínima: {p.TempMin}";
     }
```

must be a joke.

in this case your code could be more simple

```
var dateTime= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-20);

var productList= await ( from p in _context.Produtos
                     where (p.Nome == city && dateTime >= ... )
                     select p).ToListAsync();
_context.Produtos.RemoveRange(productList);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```